# Divide dictionary into two dictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have one dictionary. For e.g. wholeDict. , which contains no. of dictionaries. I want to create two dictionaries say dict1 & dict2 containing equal no. of dictionaries from wholeDict. In objective -c how to perform this? Anyone have solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered in Objective-C, how do you want to decide which elements will a half contain?

Comment: "containing equal no. of dictionaries from wholeDict" And if the nb of dict is 3? What `wholeDict` looks like? You can get `allKeys`, and "divide/distribute" then. What decide to put the subDict in `dict1` or `dict2`

Comment: suppose i want to insert up to 100 elements of wholeDict in dict1 and all remaining in dict2 then how to do?

Comment: Use `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code and state why it doesn't work or why you are not happy with it. If you're really stuck for an algorithm consider being given a box full of ping-pong balls and two empty boxes with the instruction to divide the balls between the two empty boxes. How would you solve it? Now code the method you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways to do this, but one option is to enumerate "whole" and alternate which dictionary you append to:

```
- (void)splitDicts
{
    // This is just me creating sample data for the "whole" dictionary.
    NSMutableDictionary *whole = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Valus is %d", i];
        whole[key] = value;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    __block BOOL addToDict1 = YES;

    [whole enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (addToDict1)
        {
            dict1[key] = obj;
        }
        else
        {
            dict2[key] = obj;
        }
        addToDict1 = !addToDict1;
    }];
}
```